# No response after submitting form on iPad from UIWebView

Tags: forms, ipad, uiwebview

I am currently opening a webpage in UIWebView and submitting a form which performs a query on the server side and youtube video is returned (if available). I have no say/control over the server side implementation.

This webview works fine on iPhone/iPod, however, when I try to run the same app on iPad there is no response after submitting the form.

I created a dummy app, compiled on iOS 3.2 and problem is still there.

I put NSLogs in webview delegate methods which shows that after the form is submitted (UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted) nothing happens.

I'm unable to figure out why this happens only on iPad and not on iPhone/iPod Touch.

I have created the webview in IB and setting the URL is viewDidLoad

```
[viewTourWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.realestatetour.com/mobiletours.htm"]]];
```

The URL for reference is *http://www.realestatetour.com/mobiletours.htm*
Enter the Tour ID as *10*.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it wasn't working is because the form opens the result in a new page, (i.e. _blank) and apparantly all links opening in new window are ignored by uiwebview and its delegates.

I found 2 possible solutions for this:

1) Modifying the html using javascript to replace all _blank with _self for all anchor tags.
([source](http://peter.boctor.net/2009/05/26/displaying-pop-ups-in-a-uiwebview/))

2) A more elegant solution which works for handling links which open a new window.
([source](http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/09/14/making-target-_blank-links-work-in-a-uiwebview/))

In my case i recreated the web page displaying form on the iphone app and changed _blank to _self.